# When i send a message on my app it only says hello world instead of the text im typing

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
      // Get the message from the intent    
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();
}
```

Comment: how you send message to this class?

Comment: what exactly do you mean with send message to this class (sorry im new)

Comment: see answers, they say true, you must delete following line : `setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);`

Comment: Next time you should provide some additional details, like where are you calling that method, after which steps, etc., it will help the SO community to help better.

Comment: Please mark this question as answered.

Comment: ok thanks sorry im new to this ^^ how can i mark it as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting your content view on the activity with:

```
setContentView(textView);
```

but then you are overriding it with your second call to `setContentView`:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
```

Remove `setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);`. You should always call `setContentView` only once on your Activity's `onCreate` method.

Answer (score 2):

First, you make a textview, and put it on the screen:

```
// Set the text view as the activity layout
setContentView(textView);
```

then you remove it from the screen, by setting the contents from below XML on the screen.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
// Show the Up button in the action bar.
```

So first call above line, then do `findViewById()` to find the textview from that xml, and then change the text. Or just not-call above xml ofcourse.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `setContentView()` twice. First you are passing the `TextView` and then, I am assuming, you are passing a layout file that contains a `TextView` with the "Hello, World" text.